# Can ElasticSearch run in JBoss EAP 6?

Tags: elasticsearch, jboss-eap-6

I found the article here "http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/master/_deploying_in_jboss_eap6_module.html".

But I don't see how to deploy the webapp? Is this for deploying dependencies for an ElasticSearch client running within a webapp to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/javanna/elasticsearch-war-example). Need to use the elasticsearch-transport-wares plugin.

Comment: that link is dead :(